# C3 donut chart with data from JSON object

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to create a [C3 donut chart](https://c3js.org/samples/chart_donut.html) using data from a `JSON` object stored in a variable. The title renders correctly but the columns don't. If I hard code the column data (see commented out line) the chart renders but if I try to parse the column data from a `JSON` object it fails. However when I console log the column data ( in variable 'theatres'), it looks correct.

```
const txt = '{"theatres":"[[\'AMER INT\',386],[\'AMER US\',464],[\'APAC\',914],[\'EMEA\',706],[\'JP\',81]]","title":"94 Countries"}';

const dataobj = JSON.parse(txt);

var theatres = dataobj.theatres;
var title = dataobj.title;

console.log(dataobj);
console.log(theatres);

var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {

type: 'donut',
         //     columns: [['AMER INT',386],['AMER US',464],['APAC',914],['EMEA',706],['JP',81]]
        columns: theatres
    },
    size: {
        height: 800
    },
    donut: {
        title: title
    }
});
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the value of `theatres` is still string:

```
"[['AMER INT', 386], ['AMER US', 464],  ['APAC', 914],  ['EMEA', 706],  ['JP', 81]]"
```

So you need to use `eval()` to evaluate as valid array

```js
const txt = '{"theatres":"[[\'AMER INT\',386],[\'AMER US\',464],[\'APAC\',914],[\'EMEA\',706],[\'JP\',81]]","title":"94 Countries"}';

const dataobj = JSON.parse(txt);

var theatres = dataobj.theatres;
var title = dataobj.title;
//console.log(dataobj);
//console.log(theatres);

var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {

        type: 'donut',
        columns: eval(theatres)
    },
    size: {
        height: 350
    },
    donut: {
        title: title
    }
        });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.20/c3.min.js"></script>
    
<div id="chart"></div>
```